# Resource Rules Configuration for Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is anyone using Apps Script and UrlFetchApp with useIntranet:true?  If so, can you provide your  node in resourceRules.xml in the SDC agent config?  The documentation has no information about this and I keep getting a Address unavailable error, even know the resource works for Gadgets.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the Google documentation for [Installing and Configuring](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/docs/1.3/config) the SDC.  To use Apps Scripts, the  element should be `<service>Apps-Script</service>`.

When using `<service>Apps Script</service>` and specifying an appId, the SDC agent will throw an error and not start.